# Svg containers not positioning properly

Tags: html, svg, d3.js

[image]

I'm trying to get two svg containers to line up but one of them is behaving strangely. In the picture above both the the containers have their x and y coordinates set to 0, but the "svgImages" container is much further over to the right then it should be. You can see that the width is 483px, which means that with an x-coordinate of 0 the right edge of the container should be at ~250px. I made a tooltip to debug (top-left corner) and it's showing the right edge at about 330. Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: sounds like your css positioning may be off, change the position of both containers to absolute in the css

Comment: Try giving them width and height attributes and see if that helps.

Comment: Add the markup showing the problem. I imagine you've just drawn what's in the `<svg>` tag further to the right but it's impossible to do anything other than guess at the moment.